# Capybara Poltergeist get element text

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I've got a line of code that can will get the contents of an element on the page with any driver but poltergeist. Is this expected behavior for poltergeist and if so, how can I do this in a way that works with poltergeist?

Here is the Ruby

```
page.find( item_price_selector(3) ).native.text
```

Here is the error

```
Failure/Error: price = page.find( item_price_selector(3) ).native.text
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `text' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Node:0xb07db1c>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
page.find( item_price_selector(3) ).native.text
```

The `native` is unnecessary. Removing it and causes it to run correctly in all drivers

```
page.find( item_price_selector(3) ).text
```